# Create database using SQLite on Eclipse

Tags: sql, android, sqlite

I am creating an android application using Eclipse. I want to ask on how to create a database using SQLite. The database will only have 3 tables which is user_id, user_name, and user_password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Formulate `CREATE` statements for your tables.
2. (a) on desktop create a SQLite db and then push the directory to emulator. Use SQLite command line to execute these statements, or

   (b) [connect to android shell then you will get SQLite shell](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/debugging-database). or

   (c) in your android activity, fire SQL command (as mentioned by `user522751` )

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it really did help me in understanding SQLite. However, I researched some informations on how to create database and I found out that there is a SQLite Database Browser. I am wondering if how could I import the created database into Eclipse IDE.

Comment: what do u mean by importing db into Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You can try SQLiteOpenHelper, here is what i did in a demo app few weeks ago..
import static com.kevin.fastcard.utils.ColumnConstants.*;
import static com.kevin.fastcard.utils.DBConstants.*;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TBL_NAME + "(" + _ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + QUESTION + " TEXT,"
            + ANSWER + " TEXT," + CATEGORY + " TEXT," + CREATE_TIME
            + " TEXT," +TIME_IN_MILLIS+" INTEGER"+ ");");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.delete(TBL_NAME, null, null);
}
```

}

I'm new to android, hope that can help you..

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm also a newbie in android. Have you tried using the SQLite Database Browser?